# Another sticky footer / 100% height div with clean code

Tags: html, css

I am trying to write clean code without wrappers.
So let me give an example

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <header>Header and nav section (Leaving nav in header is good way?)</header>
    <article>Main content. This part should stretch</article>
    <aside>Not so important but desktop view still have place for it</aside>
    <footer>Just footer but sticky</footer>
</body>
```

The first try was to give footer a

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
```

and for body

```
margin: 0 0 100px;
```

after this just set `min-height: 100%;` to html and it works fine.
Now I'm trying to pin aside just at the top of the footer and I can't because I need to stretch the article to cover the rest of the page.

And finally the question:
How can you achieve this if the size of the aside changes depending on the subsite, and I don't want to use wrappers because they are kind of ugly?

Additionally is it possible to use **html5/css3** magic (I found advice to use flex but without example...) and still have compatibility with ie8. Usage of XP is still huge in my country sadly.

I spent a couple of days on SO and I found many examples using wrap for the whole page that includes footer or wrap for header and content that leaves footer as another box, but that's not what I want.

## Update

I partially found the solution.
[Link to snippet](http://cbracco.me/css-sticky-footer-effect/)

But now I have another strange problem.
Here is example [my page](http://krzes.com/tmp/)

I have an empty space below the footer and according to dev tool in chrome and IE this part belongs nowhere.
How is this possible?

Comment: The proper way to spell "asside" is "aside".  That should resolve issues unrelated to this question.

Comment: I have no excuse for this mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

1.footer should be position fixed
2.for body: dont use margin, use `position:fixed; bottom:100px;`
3.min-height:100%. Well, this is kinda nonsense. Simply use `height:100%;`

Comment: 1. What I shouldn't use? Probably SO formatting get rid of your code.

Comment: `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<footer>` all act like `<div>`s in browsers that don't support semantic HTML5. It is *recommended* that these be used wherever possible, as they have no adverse effect in old browsers (as long as the `DOCTYPE` is `html5`), and can provide an enhanced UX in modern browsers.

Comment: @JulesMazur You are right, tough I like to use divs because they're cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: @gergalyb in that case why not leave the navbar in the `<header>`?